# Не работает fetch запрос внутри observer

Tags: javascript, fetch, observer

У меня есть `fetch` запрос внутри `observer`, в котором я делаю проверку на наличие элемента в DOM, но сам запрос `fetch`, не работает.

Если я вынесу `fetch` из `observer`, то запрос `fetch` будет выполнятся.

Пожалуйста, помогите.

```
let observer = new MutationObserver(() => {
    if (document.querySelector("any_selector")) {
        let options = {
            method: "GET",
            headers: { Accept: "application/json", "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        };

        fetch("https://any_url", options)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then(get_any_data);

        function get_any_data(data) {
            console.log("Work!!!");
        }

        observer.disconnect();
    }
});
observer.observe(document.querySelector("body"), { childList: true });
```

Comment: Т.е. если первой строкой внутри `if` добавить `console.log(123)` - это сработает?

Comment: ... может надо добавить `subtree: true`

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg, *"Т.е. если первой строкой внутри if добавить console.log(123) - это сработает?"* - да, сработает. `subtree: true` - не помог

Comment: Все здесь работает https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-hill-7cpc6v?file=/src/index.js

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg, странно, почему у меня не пашет?! Ну спасибо, буду разбираться.